# What is the optimum way to create XML using MSXML

Tags: xml, vba, msxml

At the moment I am creating XML like this - and it works great...

```
Private Function CreateDom()
    Dim dom
    Set dom = New DOMDocument
    dom.async = False
    dom.validateOnParse = False
    dom.resolveExternals = False
    dom.preserveWhiteSpace = True
    Set CreateDom = dom
End Function

Public Function generateXML(sourceFileLocation)

'I make an instance of the dom

Set dom = CreateDom

'This is how I setup a root node

Set rootXML= dom.createElement("root")
    dom.appendChild rootXML

'This is how I set attributes
questestinterop.setAttribute "attributeName", "attributeValue"

'setup a child node
Set childOfRoot = dom.createElement("childOfRoot")
rootXML.appendChild childOfRoot 

'This is how I set the text of the element

childOfRoot.Text = "Text Value"
End Function
```

This is ok in my basic example above, but lets say I have a greater amount of XML to create - I end up with LOADS of appendchilds and a lot of objects - this seams inefficient and prone to error - but has the advantage that I can add an object to a previously created one, at any point.

With MSXML I don't have InnerXML available to me so the code is verbose. I am after a more effective way of creating XML using MSXML and VBA/VB - or a best practice for this kind of work - I can't help but feel there is a better way.

**UPDATE**
I mentioned above there was no InnerXML - but there is a way to load an XML snippet into the DOM

```
Sub MergeXML()

   'Define
   Dim oXml As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
   Dim oXml2 As New MSXML2.DOMDocument

   'Assign
   oXml.loadXML ("<SomeRootElement><Input></Input></SomeRootElement>")
   oXml2.loadXML ("<Output><SomeElement></SomeElement></Output>")
   'or assign via file
   'oXml.Load("c:\Xml.xml")
   'oXml2.Load("c:\Xml2.xml")

   'Process
   oXml.FirstChild.appendChild oXml2.selectSingleNode("//Output")

   'Destroy
   oXml.Save ("c:\NewXml.xml")
   Set oXml2 = Nothing
   Set oXml = Nothing

End Sub
```

source: http://p2p.wrox.com/beginning-vb-6/28319-xml-using-msxml2-domdocument-object.html

Comment: This code is from VBA but will still work in VB.net - MSXML methods remain the same

Comment: use serialize classes like following webpage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274147/update-multi-table-dataset-via-datagridview-vb#comment48680953_30274147

Comment: Is `Set` still valid in VB.Net?  Also, add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file or set it in your project's properties.

Comment: There are a number of  solutions for VB.NET which will not work in VBA. And what is optimal for one may not be so for the other. If you are not after a .NET solution, please remove the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is often the representation of an object stored in a file. .Net has many popular package available that make serialization and deserialization very easily, enabling you to generate xml from object and object from xml.

VBA lacks the possibility of using those nice package, but I've used a module that essentially does the same. http://www.kudinov.ru/?p=21

This allows you to focus on constructing your class and manipulate your data. The module will take care of the XML creation for you.

**UPDATE:**

First create your Parent class

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ParentClassContainer"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Explicit
Public Persons() As ChildClassWithEveryXmlAttributes
```

Secondly create your child class

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "ChildClassWithEveryXmlAttributes"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

Option Explicit
Public FirstName As String
Public LastName as String
Public Birdthday as date
```

Third, make sure to include the serialize module

Lastly, you can use your objects and serialize it at the end

```
Sub testSerialize()
    Dim myObject As New ParentClassContainer
    Redim myObject.Persons(20)
    myObject.Persons(0).FirstName = "John"
    myObject.Persons(0).LastName = "Doe"
    myObject.Persons(0).Birdthday = #2015-05-21#

    Serialize myObject, "C:\test.xml", False
End Sub
```

So we have created an xml file without ever playing with the createElement and appendChild functions from msxml. This is less prone to error because you play with objects.

**XML Output result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Object class="ParentClassContainer">
    <PropertyGet name="Persons" type="VT_EMPTY">
        <Object class="ChildClassWithEveryXml">
            <PropertyGet name="FirstName" type="VT_BSTR">
                <![CDATA[John]]>
            </PropertyGet>
            <PropertyPut name="FirstName" type="VT_BSTR"/>
            <PropertyGet name="LastName" type="VT_BSTR">
                <![CDATA[Doe]]>
            </PropertyGet>
            <PropertyPut name="LastName" type="VT_BSTR"/>
            <PropertyGet name="Birdthday" type="VT_DATE">
                <![CDATA[2015-05-21]]>
            </PropertyGet>
            <PropertyPut name="Birdthday" type="VT_DATE"/>
        </Object>
    </PropertyGet>
    <PropertyPut name="Persons" type="VT_VARIANT"/>
    <PropertyPutRef name="Persons" type="VT_EMPTY"/>
</Object>
```

I created an excel file for this, I don't know how to upload it here or if it's possible...

[Sample excel file with Vba as requested](http://ge.tt/5PrQvtG2/v/0?c)

Comment: This is intriguing - are you able to provide an example of how the method is different from what im doing in my example? is it less code

Comment: this is better than it was but its still not clear how this creates XML or how parent child relationships work. Can you improve your answer by show the resulting XML from your example?

Comment: In pure VBA serialization is impossible. Also, registering COM servers for users is a bit of stretch for Excel-VBA solutions, as one of the chief charms  of Excel tools is that they don't have any deployment overhead. As in this example serialization is done via some wrapper, probably a C# wrapper, so it will need deployment.